# Prevent redirect page in Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I configure a file upload ability on my website. The program work like a charm! Though I use Ajax to handle the php response. The problem is that when I click `submit` it redirects me to php and don't return the `echo` back to my ajax. I tried `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` to Ajax but dodn't work.

Here are my files

HTML

```
<form style="margin-top: -20px; width: inherit; cursor: default;" name="photo" id="imageUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" action="../lib/imgUpload.php">
      <input type="file" name="image" id="ImageBrowse"  style='//visibility:hidden;'>
      <button type="submit" name="upload" id="UploadImageBtn" value="Upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //many many other functions

    $('#imageUploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('bad');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();

    }));

    $("#ImageBrowse").on("change", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#imageUploadForm").submit();
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];      
    $targetPath = "profile_avatars/".$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $res = move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; 
    if ($res) {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "no";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try your browser console, may be there are some JS errors, which interrupt JS execution.

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan I use `Firebug` for  testing. No errors. I also tried another browser and I have the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute e.preventDefault() before the other lines of code, like this:

```
$('#imageUploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url: "../lib/imgUpload.php",
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('bad');
        }
    });
});
```

There also was one round closing bracket too much at the end of this function.

Try to remove the action from your form element, and return false, like this:

```
 <form style="margin-top: -20px; width: inherit; cursor: default;" name="photo" id="imageUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Remove `method="POST"` from the form element and add it to your ajax call.

Comment: Try to return false onsubmit and remove the action. You can also define the url in your ajax call.

Comment: Could you try to remove method="POST" from your form element and define this in your Ajax call?